# Property does not exist on type Class and components angular

Tags: angular

Im building simple angular application. and i get error on component(book-add) html.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title"><span class="req">* </span> Title:</label>
    <input required type="text" [(ngModel)]="book.title" name="title" id="title"
    class="form-control phone" maxlength="28" placeholder="Enter book title..." />
                    </div>
```

**Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Book'.**

in book-add.component.ts
i intialized Book class and by default it is showing i can enter title and author so that means it recognized   Book class

```
book: Book=new Book("","");
```

this is class book.ts

```
export class Book{
    constructor(
        title:String,
        author:String
    ){}
}
```

Why i am getting this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the access modifier which turns it into a field on the type. `constructor( public title: string, public author:string){}`. Without that you are just passing in arguments that the code is completely ignoring.

```
export class Book{
    constructor(
        public title:String,
        public author:String
    ){}
}
```

Comment: this resolved my problem, thank you very much